# Save formatting as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, wysihtml5

I am using [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) and [bootsrap-wysihtml5-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails) for a text editor. This will be sort of a double-pronged question. I have the bold/italic/underline etc working in the form but it doesn't save as html.
It looks like this:

```
<b>Title</b>
```

when it should look like this:

**Title**

What should i add to save the form as html?

Second question: image uploads take a link and then wrap them with an image tag. Is there any way that i can upload an image (through paperclip) instead?

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :body %>
<%= f.input :image %> #want this to be in the text editor add-link
<% end %>
```

comments.js.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
 $(".wysihtml5").each (i, elem) ->
   $(elem).wysihtml5()
```